# How to paste into a terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, command

I have copied a URL, such as `git://gitorious.org/openhatch/oh-mainline.git`. I want to paste this in the terminal using a keyboard shortcut.

**Please** don't say "right click and paste."

Comment: Because I'm detail-oriented: "bash" is not a terminal. bash is a shell program that the user communicates with using a terminal.

Comment: "right click and paste" muahahaha I said it

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Gnome terminal defaults to <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>

OSX terminal defaults to <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>. You can also use <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to paste the text in escaped form.

Windows 7 terminal defaults to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Insert</kbd>

Comment: Control-Shift-v also works for the [terminator terminal emulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_%28terminal_emulator%29)

Answer (score 25):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> usually works throughout X11.

Comment: `shift + INS` prints `b` in terminal.

Comment: @kracekumar, then that's the last thing you selected.

Comment: There are two clipboards (on linux systems), shift-insert pastes text which has previously been selected. Ctrl-v (or Right-click and copy) usually puts text in a different buffer, to paste from this buffer Ctrl-Shift-v (or right-click and paste).

Comment: Works in whatever terminal Puppy uses!  Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Mostly likely middle click your mouse.

Or try <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

It all depends on terminal used and X11-config for mouse.

Comment: Well middle click inserts directly without any menu if that was bothering you, and it is very fast if you already selected the text with your mouse. Else I agree a keyboard shortcut is faster.

Answer (score 10):

same for Terminator

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Look at your terminal key-bindings if any if that doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

In Konsole (KDE terminal) is the same, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

On windows 7:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ins</kbd>

works for me!

Comment: Worked on putty on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Like this article [How to copy paste text and commands in the Linux terminal](https://itsfoss.com/copy-paste-linux-terminal/#:%7E:text=Basically%2C%20when%20you%20are%20interacting,%2FV%20for%20copy%2Dpasting.) mentioned. 
You can use **middle mouse button** to implement the functionality of paste. I tested it on terminal successfully.