# Pasting into OS X command line adds extraneous characters

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line-interface, clipboard

When I paste text into the Terminal window, Terminal appends `0~` before the pasted string and `1~` after it. I've never seen this behaviour before. If I copy `foo` from anywhere (including the same Terminal window), pasting into the command line results in:

`-bash-4.2$ 0~foo1~`

I tried every method for pasting text into OS X terminal from [How to paste into a terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123709/how-to-paste-into-a-terminal), i.,e.
<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd>; <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>; <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

Pasting into text editors and browsers (basically, any place other than Terminal) does not add any extra characters. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

I'm using macOS 10.14.2; Terminal version 2.9.1.

Comment: This is more a question for https://superuser.com/ or https://apple.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Your shell's enabled the [*bracketed paste*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Bracketed-Paste-Mode) mode (originally xterm, but Terminal.app has no suitable documentation).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the actual answer for this but for me it works after restarting the terminal.

```
Command + Q
```

I will update once I will find something.